# Production code and ports

Tags: web-services, docker

I am trying to understand what is typically done in a production environment.

Say that I have an angular/mongo/express application and im using docker. I would launch the static resources with nginx or apache http all on port 80 to the client. The webservices of node and express would be in a container together exposed on port 8080. The mongo instance would be linked and exposed on 8080 as well in its own container. Next i would map the host in the linux box to the ip's of the containers. To use the web services i would call the express server with $http or if angular 4 in an observable. This would make the call to express which would send it to the mongo instance. Port 80 is the only thing that is exposed to the client as you wouldn't want to make them specify a specific port (ex. www.clienturl.com:9037). From port 80 the static resources are given which in turn call the webservices operating on other ports as needed.

Is this somewhat correct? I get confused on how all the ports correlate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I got the question right, but if you want to use docker in production (I am talking about docker alone, without any orchestrator) then my suggestion is to install a traditional (or why not a dockerized) proxy server (nginx for example) and expose your docker service through it.

For instance, if you have 2 web services in two different docker containers, you can expose them to port 8080 and 8081. Then, with a simple configuration, you would route requests coming into your server on port 80 (where the proxy is listening) based on the hostname (a classical name based virtual host).

This is one of the simplest methods I can think  of in order to use docker in "production" without an orchestrator.

Comment: what did you mean by orchestrator?

Comment: an orchestrator is a software that takes care of a multitude of containers, how they interact and a lot more. Examples are `kubernetes`, `docker swarm`, `mesos`